# Evenly distribute elements in columns

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I have a single div named `.wrap` within which items are placed. An unknown amount of items (`.thing`) should be arranged into four columns (stacking on top of each other).

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="thing"> thing1 </div>
    <div class="thing"> thing2 </div>
    ...
</div>
```

The columns need to be evenly distributed so that no column is empty. This would be very easy using:

```
.wrap {
    column-count: 4;
    column-fill: balance;
}
```

However, `column-fill` only works in Firefox, I believe.

**Is there another CSS method to achieve this layout in all recent versions of browsers?** Specifically, would flexbox be able to help here?

Please note that I cannot add extra divs to act as columns, and do not want a JS solution.

Here is a fiddle which has the desired layout except for the even distribution → http://jsfiddle.net/bpdtkmmt/

Comment: `no column is empty`. With what you need to fill empty space, with `.thing` width or margin between them?

Comment: @Narek-T The last column (fourth) appears empty, at least for me. I'm using Chrome 47 on mac.

Comment: For me too, but what there should be? Sorry for my english) You have 9 items and you want to split them into 4 columns. What is browser need to do? If you place 8 items last column will not be empty.

Comment: Currently it has 3 in each column. It *should* have 3 in one column, and 2 in each of the remaining. I want the browser to evenly distribute them to all columns (as best as possible).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use Flexbox here—and it should get the job done for the most part. It's sort of hacky and you have abandon using CSS column rules. There is somewhat less variability, so if you add any further rows/columns, you will have to change values. In order to preserve the number of columns per row, you will need to set a fixed or percentage height for the wrapper. From there, you establish the wrapper container as a flex container with the `display: flex` rule and establish multiple columns using either `flex-direction: column` and `flex-wrap: wrap` or the shorthand `flex-flow: column wrap`.

To make sure each column has x number of items in it, you will need to use the `flex-basis` rule and set to the percentage of the column you want to fill up. So a column with 3 items would have `flex-basis: 33.33%`. You indicated you want several rows of 3 items then a couple of rows of 2 items, so will need to use the `nth-child` or `nth-of-type` selector to establish a new flex-basis of `50%` starting at the 10th element. And of course, you will have to establish a percentage for the width you want the thing element to take up on the page (4 rows = 25%). To make sure all elements are equally sized, you need to use the

However, the centering the text in a flexbox remains a problem and you will have to establish the things as flex containers by setting `display` to `flex` or `inline-flex` with a `flex-direction` of `column`, along with `text-align` and `justify-content` properties set to `center`.

```
justify-content: center; 
flex-direction: column;
text-align: center
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hxcnoxx9/10/

This CSS should solve your problems.

```
.wrap {
    height: 180px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, tomato 0%, tomato 25%, slategrey 25%, slategrey 50%, tomato 50%, tomato 75%, slategrey 75%);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.thing {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
    color: #fff;
    width: 25%;
    flex-basis: 33.33%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
}

.thing:nth-child(1n+10) {
   flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking a look! I'm OK with abandoning css columns, however I have two issues with this solution. 1) I don't know how many items will eventually be in there, so I can't just set a fixed height and 2) Try removing two '.thing' divs in your example. It goes down to three columns.

Comment: Alas, AFAIK a flexbox solution with a fixed # of columns requires a fixed height and knowing the number of divs unless you have a JS solution to calculate # of divs/columns. 

I don't think it's possible to do this in purely CSS. If you want to maintain four columns while removing divs, it's just some simple math: change the nth-child rule `thing:nth-child(1n+4)` and the other columns will have two items. The `flex-basis` is essentially a height of an element in a column in this case.

Comment: This solution is not great, as it requires a fixed height for the container, which, if you have a fluid number of items, is often unknown in advance. It seems `column-count` is now much more widely supported though: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count

Answer (score 2):

In 2022, you can now safely use `column-count` as this is [fully supported across all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count).

Example:

```
.wrap {
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 1rem;
}
```