# Grow a div without moving anything else

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I have 4 div (red, yellow, green, blue )
In my case, I have 2 per row.
I need to grow the second (yellow) without having a gap under the red, only the blue must be going down to follow the yellow.

I have a code pen If you want try .
[Code](https://codepen.io/czechsebastian/pen/eYYeVKY)

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-item-group>
      <v-container>
        <div class="row">
          <v-col
            v-for="(item, index) in colors"
            :key="index"
            cols="12"
            md="6"
          >
              <v-card
                class="align-center"
                height="auto"
                :color="item.color"
              >
                <v-card-text v-for="(c, ind) in item.content" :key="ind" @click="colors[index].content.push(c)">{{c}}</v-card-text>
              </v-card>
          </v-col>
        </div>
      </v-container>
    </v-item-group>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    colors: [{color: 'red', content: ['sample content']},
            {color: 'yellow', content: ['sample content']},
            {color: 'green', content: ['sample content']},
            {color: 'blue', content: ['sample content']}]
  }
})
```

Comment: Related: [Evenly distribute elements in columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34274552/evenly-distribute-elements-in-columns) Summary: It may not be possible to do it cleanly.

Comment: You are saying you want yellow to grow vertically so the green is not pushed  down? If so, you can put red & green in one col (6 width) & yellow & blue in the second column (6 width)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to have divs grow without spaces, You need to use display : flex and flex direction

> In the below code, I've considered tow columns of colors growing
>   vertically

**You can have N number of colors**

> Working codepen here:
>   https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/GRROyQZ?editors=1010

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div>
    <div  style="width:50%; float: left;display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;">
      <div  v-for="(color, index) in colors" :key="index" v-if="index % 2 == 0 && index == 0">
        <v-card height="auto"
          :color="colors[index].color"
                >
          <v-card-text v-for="(c, ind) in colors[index].content" :key="ind" @click="colors[index].content.push(c)">
            {{c}}
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </div>
      <div v-for="(color, index) in colors" :key="index" style="flex-grow: 1;" v-if="index % 2 == 0 && index != 0">
        <v-card height="auto"
          :color="colors[index].color"
                >
          <v-card-text v-for="(c, ind) in colors[index].content" :key="ind" @click="colors[index].content.push(c)">
            {{c}}
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div  style="width:50%;float: left;display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;">
      <div v-for="(color, index) in colors" :key="index" v-if="index % 2 == 1 && index == 1">
        <v-card height="auto"
          :color="colors[index].color"
                >
          <v-card-text v-for="(c, ind) in colors[index].content" :key="ind" @click="colors[index].content.push(c)">
            {{c}}
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </div>
      <div style="flex-grow: 1;" v-for="(color, index) in colors" :key="index" v-if="index % 2 == 1 && index != 1">
        <v-card height="auto"
          :color="colors[index].color"
                >
          <v-card-text v-for="(c, ind) in colors[index].content" :key="ind" @click="colors[index].content.push(c)">
            {{c}}
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    colors: [{color: 'red', content: ['sample content']},
            {color: 'yellow', content: ['sample content']},
            {color: 'green', content: ['sample content']},
            {color: 'blue', content: ['sample content']},
            {color: 'pink', content: ['sample content']},
            {color: 'grey', content: ['sample content']},
            {color: 'orange', content: ['sample content']},
            {color: 'indigo', content: ['sample content']},
            {color: 'purple', content: ['sample content']},
            {color: 'cyan', content: ['sample content']},
            {color: 'teal', content: ['sample content']}]
  }
})
```